# Change edge information display in Blender 2.80 with python

Tags: python, mesh, edges

I am currently porting my personal addons to Blender 2.8 and this used to work fine in 2.79:

```
me = bpy.context.object.data        
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) 
me.show_edge_seams = True
me.show_edge_crease = False
me.show_edge_sharp = False
me.show_edge_bevel_weight = False
```

In 2.8 this does not work anymore. It seems to be an option of the overlay system now but I can't find any python documentation about it (I know, probably too early). Does anybody know how to access the edges view state in 2.8 with python? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution if anybody needs this information:

```
overlay = context.space_data.overlay

overlay.show_edge_seams  = True
overlay.show_edge_bevel_weight = False
overlay.show_edge_crease = False
overlay.show_edge_sharp = False
```

Documentation:
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.View3DOverlay.html